# Concatenate two video files to single video in players

Tags: video, jwplayer, cloudinary, flowplayer, transloadit

In my web application I have multiple mp4 video files and would like to play those video files as a single video in different order in web browser player.

I'm not looking for any external software / online converter. I need the merging option in my web application itself.

Example:

video 1 (10 mints) and video 2 (10 mints). Now the player should show play back time as 20 mints and video should play as a single video.

If you could give a good advice I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

download a good video  analyser from the web like free video cutter joiner and do the job.

Comment: It's a web application, So can't use 'video cutter joiner'. Need some solution to merge and play in the browser player itself.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question and command. I'm not looking for any external software / online converter. I need the merging option in my web application itself.

Answer (score 0):

While, this was asked a while ago, you may find this helpful as I know you weren't looking for an external service, but I also noticed that you tagged our service. I work for Transloadit and you may be interested in our Community plan, which offers you 5GB of encoding data for free.

By using the [Transloadit video concatenation robot](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/#video-concat) you can supply and stitch videos together, and you have the option to send it to a digital storage service such as [S3](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/#s3-store).

For example this template here will encode a video, import another MP4 from a link and then stitch them together to be exported to Amazon S3:

```
{
  ":original": {
    "robot": "/upload/handle"
  },
  "preroll_imported": {
    "robot": "/http/import",
    "result": true,
    "url": "https://demos.transloadit.com/inputs/waves10.mp4"
  },
  "concatenated": {
    "use": {
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": ":original",
          "as": "video_1"
        },
        {
          "name": "preroll_imported",
          "as": "video_2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "robot": "/video/concat",
    "result": true,
    "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1",
    "preset": "ipad-high"
  },
  "exported": {
    "use": [
      "concatenated"
    ],
    "robot": "/s3/store",
    "credentials": "YOUR_AWS_CREDENTIALS"
  }
}
```